# Cron job running, but not overwriting file

Tags: php, json, cron

I have the following set as a cron job:

```
*/1 * * * * /usr/bin/php /var/www/html/recalls/php/savesjson.php
```

I checked the status and I get this back.

```
Mar 10 16:29:01 big-hoster CRON[30417]: (root) CMD (/usr/bin/php /var/www/html/recalls/php/savesjson.php)
Mar 10 16:29:02 big-hoster CRON[30416]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
```

The savesjson.php file should execute and basically save a new JSON file (`current.json`) in the same directory. If I just run this file (by going to the URL), it works perfectly. However, my cron isn't actually updating the `current.json` file.

`current.json` has permissions as follows:

```
-rwxr--r-- 1 root root 0 Mar 10 16:17 /var/www/html/recalls/php/current.json
```

`savesjson.php` has permissions as follows:

```
-rwxr-xr-x 1 www-data www-data 213 Mar  8 14:11 /var/www/html/recalls/php/savesjson.php
```

What am I missing here?

**UPDATE**: If I try to execute from the CLI, like so:

```
# /usr/bin/php /var/www/html/recalls/php/savesjson.php
```

It appears to execute, but the script doesn't do what it's supposed to (create new file) and there are no errors in my PHP logs. However, the PHP does work if I go directly to the URL (example.com/php/savesjson.php).

Comment: Hi there, try to execute PHP from CLI instead by going to the URL. Try cheking PHP error logs to get some idea whats going on.

Comment: @FernandoMertins Tried from the CLI and it appears to run, but doesn't actually do what it's supposed to (generate a new file). There's nothing in the PHP error logs

Comment: Hi, ok... PHP version and SO?

Comment: Hi, I have a cron job like this: `/usr/local/bin/php -f /var/www/html/recalls/php/savesjson.php`

Comment: @FernandoMertins PHP is 7.0, not sure what "SO" even means